# About cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

> A cyclic group of order $10$ has an element a such that the set $$\left\{ a^4 , a^7 , a^6 \right\}$$ has exactly two elements. How many elements are in the set $$\left\{ a^{3n} : n \text{ is a positive integer} \right\}$$ Explain your reasoning!

I am not quite sure if I got it right but I'm thinking that the only elements of the first set will just be the identity $e$ and $a$ where the inverse of $a$ is itself. In that sense, those with even exponents will be the identity $e$ while those with odd exponents will be $a$. Thus I could say that the next set will also have two elements.. I am really confused. Am I on the right track? Also if I right $e$ and $a$ as elements how can I show a clearer explanation for it? Because it doesn't really say something about subgroups so that $e$ is not necessarily there. But then am I forced to put it there since there should only be 2 elements? Please help.

Comment: You need to find a.  It's not given.

Comment: how am I gonna find this $a$? what should I use? thanks by the way for the reply.

Comment: From the three relations $a^4=a^7, a^4=a^6, a^7=a^6,$ you can find the element $a.$ Then it's easy to find the required set. (Hints: in $\mathbb Z/10\mathbb Z,$ the element $a$ is $\bar 5.$)

Comment: Thanks Krish for commenting. I will try though i'm still really confused or I might be over thinking things. :D

Comment: How can you say $a^4 = a^7 = a^6$? The set has two elements, meaning one is distinct from the other two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S = \{a^4, a^6, a^7\}$ and consider the order of $a$, $|a|$. By the Fundamental Theorem of Cyclic Groups, $|a|$ is either $1$, $2$, $5$, or $10$. If $|a| = 1$, then $S = \{e, e, e\} = \{e\}$; if $|a| = 2$, then $S = \{e, e, a\} = \{e, a\}$; if $|a| = 5$, then $S = \{a^4, a, a^2\}$; if $|a| = 10$, then $S = \{a^4, a^6, a^7\}$. So the only possible case is when $|a| = 2$ and $S = \{e, a\}$.

Hence, we have that:
\begin{align*}
\underbrace{\{a^{3n} \mid n \in \mathbb N\}}_A
= \{a^3, a^6, a^9, a^{12}, \ldots\}
= \{a, e, a, e, \ldots\}
= S
\end{align*}

If that argument isn't rigorous enough for you, you could also do an element chasing argument. Since $\gcd(2, 3) = 1$, notice that $A \subseteq \langle a^3 \rangle = \langle a \rangle = S$. The reverse inclusion follows by noting that $e, a \in A$ if we take $n \in \{2, 1\} \subseteq \mathbb N$. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been very useful. I couldn't vote because I lack the so called reputation.. But then again, thanks a lot!